# Phoronix call to undefined function glob()

Tags: linux, unit-testing, benchmarking

I tried to installed and run phoronix test on ARMv7l.

- I built PHP 7.1.3 for ARM with extension DOM, JSON, SimpleXML, ZIP.
- My configure script is like this

  export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
  export link_zlib_arm_library=-L/home/user/zlib/zlib-1.2.11
  export link_libxml2_arm_library=-L/home/user/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.4
  export link_arm_library="${link_zlib_arm_library} ${link_libxml2_arm_library}"
  export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}"gcc "${link_arm_library}
  export CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}"g++ "${link_arm_library}
  ./configure --host=arm-linux --target=arm_linux --prefix=/opt/php \
  --disable-short-tags \
  --without-mysql --without-pear --disable-all \
  --enable-dom --enable-json --enable-simplexml --enable-zip \
  --enable-libxml
- After run the configure script, make, I copy php, php-cli and phpdbg into my ARM device /usr/lib
- When I tried to run "phoronix-test-suite", I got this error

  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function glob() in /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/objects/phodevi/phodevi.php:68
  Stack trace:
  /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/objects/phodevi/phodevi.php(496): phodevi::load_sensors()
  /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/objects/phodevi/phodevi.php(733): phodevi::initial_setup()
  /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/pts-core.php(300): include('/usr/share/phor...')
  /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/objects/pts_strings.php(175): __autoload('phodevi')
  /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/pts-core.php(80): pts_strings::add_trailing_slash('/home/root')
  /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/pts-core.php(133): pts_core::user_home_directory()
  /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/pts-core.php(29): pts_define_directories()
  /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/objects/client/pts_client.php(72): pts_core::init()
  /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/phoronix-test-suite.php(100): pts_client::init()
  {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/objects/phodevi/phodevi.php on line 68
- Please help me to find out the reason. My PHP version is already supported glob() function.